# Future tense in the if-clause

Tags: conditionals, future-constructions

I've heard it is *not* impossible to have the future tense in the if-clause of a conditional, but it is not common. I wonder which of the following statements sounds more natural.

1. Even if AI algorithms **are not going to be** powerful enough to provide reliable outcomes in the near future, they may still help optimize the process of collecting feedback from human users.
2. Even if AI algorithms **will not be** powerful enough to provide reliable outcomes in the near future, they may still help optimize the process of collecting feedback from human users.
3. Even if AI algorithms **are not** powerful enough to provide reliable outcomes in the near future, they may still help optimize the process of collecting feedback from human users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences (1) and (2) have essentially the same meaning, and both are quite natural. The choice is simply a matter of style.

Sentence (3) is valid and natural, but it has a different meaning. Sentences (1) and (2) are discussing algorithms that may be developed in the future.
Sentence (3) is is discussing results that may be obtained in the near future from algorithms that exist now.